# Webform email duplicates uploaded file

Tags: webforms

I'm using Drupal 9 and only have site admin level access and no developer support. I've also only been working with Drupal for a few months. So total newbie here; I apologize in advance.

I've created a webform which should allow external (non-registered) users to upload a file. The file should, upon submit, be emailed to a specific email address within the company. The problem that I'm running into is when the webform is emailed, the file that's uploaded is duplicated within the email. The file field is set to only allow one file per submission and the submissions stored in Drupal only show one file. The file is only duplicated in the email.

Has anyone come across this before? I've spent the last few days scouring the interwebs and haven't seen this before. I've tried adjusting the email/handler settings that I think might apply: selecting/deselecting exclude file elements with attachments, selecting/deselecting include files as attachments. I've set the email message to default, but I did look at it. Sadly with my limited skills, nothing seemed to jump out that might help. I tried excluding the field value, which just left off the attachment entirely.

I even created a new form with just a file upload field and it still duplicates. The form is 99% there - this is the last thing to work out so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The issue linked in the answer from jrockowitz contains a patch that needs be applied to the SMTP module by a developer. This probably immediately fixes your issue. Or you wait until the patch gets merged into the SMTP module and a new release gets dropped, then you can update the SMTP module containing the fix.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a known [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp/issues/2995290) to the SMTP module tracked on drupal.org.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the SMTP module installed, it looks like you might be running into a known issue.

@see https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp/issues/2995290

Comment: We do have SMTP, so that explains it. On the one hand I feel silly for not finding that (I looked for days) but on the other hand, I'm glad it's not my webform causing the problem. Thanks for the link - I now have something I can take to the higher ups in hopes we can get a developer to add the patch.